# Como cambiar la imagen de varios picture box sin escribir tanto codigo

Tags: c#

Tengo 20 picturebox a los que les quiero cambiar la imagen dependiendo de un valor.

Probé con esto

```
            if (x == 0)
        {
            CambiarImagen();
        }
        if (x == 1) 
        {
            CambiarImagen();
            pcb_Espera1.Image = Proyecto.Properties.Resources.coche1;
        }
        if (x == 2)
        {
            CambiarImagen();
            pcb_Espera1.Image = Proyecto.Properties.Resources.coche1;
            pcb_Espera2.Image = Proyecto.Properties.Resources.coche1;
        }
```

Hay alguna manera de simplificarlo sin tener que estar escribiendo cada vez mas pcb_Espera?

Comment: Pon todas las instancias en un arreglo y usa un ciclo para hacer la acción repetitiva que necesites.

Comment: que haces cuando `x=15` o `x=20`?

Comment: Lo mismo, cuando es 15 primero llamo a CambiarImagen() para quitar las imágenes de las 5 sobrantes y de ahí añadiría 15  pcb_Espera[1..2...3......15] y en el 20 no llamaría a CambiarImagen() ya que no quitare nada, las 20 tendrán imagen

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar **cambiar de perspectiva**, en vez de colocar 20 picture box y luego establecer su imagen despues, puedes aprovechar a **crear los controles picturebox mediante codigo** y establacer su imagen cuando lo creas, luego colocar el resultado en tu formulario posiocinandolos segun tu objetivo

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).